# Youtube video restriction level

Tags: php, video, youtube, youtube-api

I don't know if solution available or not for my below functionality.

I have website and i am adding youtube videos in my website with one module that have lots of youtube videos. now that video will show in frontend after user will login. but i want to show that video only if that users having gmail account. i mean video can be show only if user is logged in gmail else they can not be able to see that video. video should be private level restriction means can not be share publicly.

will it be possible? if not then is there any solution for the same to fulfill this?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your videos and set the privacyStatus to  "public","private" and "unlisted".

> [**privacyStatus**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video): The privacy status of the video. The default behavior is for an uploaded video to be publicly visible (public). When uploading test videos, you may want to specify a --privacyStatus argument value to ensure that those videos are private or unlisted. Valid values are public, private, and unlisted.

Here is the sample code:

```
// Set the video's status to "public". Valid statuses are "public",
// "private" and "unlisted".
$status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
$status->privacyStatus = "public";
```

Try using the unlisted or private if you want the video uploaded to be viewed by the uploaded only.

Hope this helps.